# I'm new to laravel, I want to delete the curriculum, it will delet the grades associated with it, and the subjcts that are associated with that grades

Tags: php, laravel, api

These are the screenshots of Curriculum,Grade and subject table, Kindly someone help me code this problem in laravel.

[Curriculum Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ecxow.png)

[image: Grade Table]

[image: Subject Table]

Comment: Does your database has cascading deletion for foreign key tables?

Comment: I don't know much about that as I'm totally new in this.

Comment: Well that's probably the first thing you need to check, it's the most likely reason why that would happen.

Comment: Sir my english is not good, I want to delete like this, and I want code for that,

Comment: StackOverflow is not a coding service. You need to code whatever you need yourself, and if / when you face an issue, then come back and ask a detailed question.

Comment: `I want code for that`...it's not about code, it's about the design of your database - you can set it to automatically delete records which are related via foreign keys...this is called a "cascading delete". You should learn about this feature and see if it meets your needs. Also "I want" is not a question and we are not a free write-my-code service. See also [ask] and the [tour].

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, everyone I have found the answer to my question, by myself.

```
public function delete(Request $request)
    {
        // todo: delete subjects and grades that fall under this curriculum
        $grades = Grade::where('curriculumId', $request->curriculumId)->pluck('id')->all();
        $subjects = Subject::where('gradeId', $grades)->pluck('id')->all();
        $sujectCount = Subject::destroy($subjects);
        $gradeCount = Grade::destroy($grades);
        $curriculumCount = Curriculum::destroy($request->curriculumId);

        return [
            'status' => 'success',
            'deletedCurriculums' => $curriculumCount,
            'deletedGrades' => $gradeCount,
            'deletedSubjects' => $sujectCount,
        ];
    }
```